# Contract a mesh (in order to make a mesh parallel to the original one)

Tags: mesh

I have a mesh and I'd like to generate a new mesh with a given distance to the original one.
I've tried scaling the mesh but since it is not squared it gets non uniform distances.

Regards

This photo is a nice example:[image]

Original question: https://blenderartists.org/t/expand-contract-mesh/467118

Comment: you mean you've made an extrusion? You need first to apply the scale of your object in Object mode if you want the thickness to be even on all the axis

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm very new at blender. I'm trying to achieve this with the extrude tool with no success. Please note that the image is a 2d (all vertex have z=0)

Comment: I guess the problem is the one I've pointed out, Your object has been scaled in Object mode, so its scale is not 1/1/1 anymore. So, in Object mode, select your object and apply its scale (ctrl A > Apply Scale), then back in Edit mode, extrude again, the thickness should be even this time